# is there any molecular transition which emits a photon in certain direction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

i know molecules having magnetic moment would be aligned in certain direction but do they emit photon in any certain direction when excited? are there any molecules which would emit photon in tthe radial direction of any fixed circle

Comment: Note that questions which are possibly answered by a simple *"Yes"* or *"No"* aren't really good questions for this site.

Comment: i just want an yes or no along with explaination